# Empty field and null values with linked tables

Tags: ms-access, null

I was using ADP project before (Access 2007) with SQL SERVER 2008.
Now I have to switch to Access 2016 which does not support ADP project, instead I have to use linked tables.

I have a issue:

In a form, when you keep a field empty or if you delete the content, Access considered it as Null, I would like it to considered the value as empty ''. It was the case with the ADP project.

The table structure refuse the Null values for some columns (main idea was to avoid ISNULL in the SQL statement for some queries, default value of the column is '')